# Load google maps API when internet is available via Ext.data.connection Sencha Touch and Phonegap

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cordova, sencha-touch

I use Sencha Touch and Phonegap to build a small app.
In this app I need the google maps API as I want to display a map.

There is a problem if the device has no internet connection, so the google maps API couldn't be loaded in the html. So I check for the internet connection.
If the internet connection is available I try to load the google maps API with Ext.data.connection:

```
var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&'; 
conn.request({  
     url: url,
     callback: function(options, success, response){
           if(response && response.responseText){
                // do something
           }
     },
     method:'GET'}
);
```

If I test the app in google chrome I receive following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;_dc=1302077479281. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

It doesn't matter if I try to invoke the HTML via `file:///` or via a webserver (`http://localhost/app`)

How can I get the google maps API and "bypass" or avoid this Access-Control-behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hering,  sorry, this won't be an easy answer.

I think you want to use a conditional script loader.  These are api's that will add the script to the document only if a condition (you have a network connection) is met.

A good one is http://yepnopejs.com/

According to this thread, it is possible to load google maps, but you must do as it says in the thread.  [Google Maps with YepNope](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/closed/#issue/11)

Specifically, include yepnope.js and remove any references to google maps.

```
yepnope([{
        load: 'http://www.google.com/jsapi',
        callback: function(){
            google.load("maps", "3", {
                callback: function(){
                    console.log("loaded");
                },
                other_params: "sensor=false"
            });
        }
    }]);
```

When it is time to render the map (which must be done after Google Maps is fully loaded) make sure you add the Ext.Map card, then call:

```
this.doLayout();
```

I think this'll work great for you, it's working for me...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this could work. I posted a solution by myself without any needs for an additional library...

Comment: With yepnope, I can do other stuff with success and failure, it's a whole API, maybe overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I found some instructions from google, so the following will work:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initializeMap";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```